# Same controller different injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make several controllers which has same logic. Only different parts are injections.

I can create controllers like this:

```
var controllerFunc = function($scope, service) {
    $scope.service = service;
}

app.controller('Controller1', ['$scope', 'Service1', controllerFunc]);
app.controller('Controller2', ['$scope', 'Service2', controllerFunc]);
```

But, it doesn't look like a AngularJS way. Are there any better ways? Or is it just good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing about your code that's "not Angular-y". Just because you haven't seen it done before doesn't mean there's anything wrong with it.

I actually have written some code like that in my projects.